# java.io.EOFException at using DataInputStream.readUTF to read String

Tags: java, datainputstream

I'm stuck on a part of a project code written in Java. The problem is every time the following method is called:

```
public static void printData(File f,int n){

   try {
       DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
       }

       dis.skipBytes(43*(n-10));

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The code crushes throwing an EOFException every time I try to skip a certain number of bytes, in other words, the program stops when it tries to read again in the second FOR loop (the first one works fine), but it seems it related to the skipBytes method... But I don't see clearly what is causing this. Any little help is welcome.

By the way, 43 is the number of bytes of each line, and n (2^9) is the number of lines written in f.

Comment: How do you initially get the value of `n`? Is it a static value or is it determined by some other code?

Comment: what value foes `43*(n-10)` equate to? How big is your file?

Answer (score 0):

See docs of DataInputStream.readUTF() method. It throws EOFException if:

```
EOFException - if this stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.
```

So, you read all bytes already or you skipped them at

```
dis.skipBytes(43*(n-10));
```